# Java 2D arrays, understanding output

Tags: java, arrays

I got this question from a previous exam paper. I am trying to understand how do you arrive to the answer: 518

> Consider the following Java program, consisting of the class Pins. Notice this is defined to have one constructor and one method named run. Both have no parameters.

```
class Pins {
    private int[][] ints = {{0,1,2}, {3,4,5},{6,7,8}};

    public Pins()
    {
        int[] a = ints[0];
        ints[0][2] = ints[0][1];
        ints[0] = ints[1];
        ints[1] = a;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        int i = -1;
        while (++i < ints.length)
        {
            int total = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < ints.length; j++) {
                if (j % 2 == 0) {
                    total += ints[i][j];
                } else {
                    total -= ints[i][j];
                }
            }

            System.out.println(total);
        }
    }
}
```

> Given an instance of this class, what is printed out by its run method? Use
>   diagrams to justify and explain your answer.

**>Why does a become {0,1,1} after the second step in the constructor and not {3,4,5} in the third step in the constructor?**

Comment: You need to 'run' the program by hand, keeping track of what's in the array and the different variables at each step. The only tricky bit is where they swap rows in the array.

Comment: I did this and I got 518 by running the program and 528 by hand

Comment: The swapping arrays bit is the bit i'm stuck at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor executes like so:

```
int[] a = ints[0];       // ints: {a: {0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}}
ints[0][2] = ints[0][1]; // ints: {a: {0,1,1}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}}
ints[0] = ints[1];       // ints: {{3,4,5}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}}; a: {0,1,1}
                         //         \-same-array/                         
ints[1] = a;             // ints: {{3,4,5}, {0,1,1}, {6,7,8}}
```

And then in `run()`, what it does, is, for every row, it computes:

```
1 + row[0] - row[1] + row[2];
```

So:

```
1 + 3 - 4 + 5 = 5
1 + 0 - 1 + 1 = 1
1 + 6 - 7 + 8 = 8
```

What's potentially tricky is that `ints` contains references to the rows, so when you say `a = ints[0]`, `a` points to the row, rather than containing a copy of it.

[image]

Comment: Why does a become {0,1,1} after the second step in the constructor and not {3,4,5} in the third step in the constructor?

Comment: `a` always points to the `{0, 1, 2 or 1}` array, it's only set in the first step and not modified afterwards. `ints[0]..ints[2]`, and `a` are all references to arrays of 3 elements somewhere else in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You see it better, if you write down the single results (just some System.out.println(...); added):

```
class Pins
{
private int[][] ints = {{0,1,2}, {3,4,5},{6,7,8}};
public Pins()
   {
    int[] a = ints[0];
    ints[0][2] = ints[0][1];
    ints[0] = ints[1];
    ints[1] = a;
   }
public void run()
   {
       for(int i=0; i < ints.length; i++){
           for(int j=0; j < ints[i].length;j++){
               System.out.print(ints[i][j]+";");
           }
           System.out.println("");
       }
   int i = -1;
   while (++i < ints.length)
      {
       int total = 1;
       for (int j = 0; j < ints.length; j++)
          {
          if (j % 2 == 0)
             {
              total += ints[i][j];
             } else
          {
           total -= ints[i][j];
          }
           System.out.println("Total:"+total);
       }
       System.out.println(total);
    }
  }

public static void main(String[] args){
    Pins pin = new Pins();
    pin.run();
}
}
```

results:

```
3;4;5;    //ints[0] after swap
0;1;1;    //ints[1] after swap
6;7;8;    //ints[2] after swap
Total:4
Total:0
Total:5
5
Total:1
Total:0
Total:1
1
Total:7
Total:0
Total:8
8
```

Comment: Why does a become {0,1,1} after the second step in the constructor and not {3,4,5} in the third step in the constructor?

Comment: Vlad answered this really good.  "a" is a reference to the values of "ints[0];" which are at that moment `{0;1;1}`. The difference is reference and value variables! In line 2 (ints[0][2] =...) you change the value, not the reference, in line 3 and 4, you just swap the references. You can imagine this like files and links to files, reference variables behave like links, value variables behave like the files directly. Only simple variables are value variables. All other (like arrays) are reference variables.

Comment: How come A doesn't change the second time round you do `int [0] [2]` = `int [0] [1]` . `public Pins()
    {
        int[] a = ints[0];
        ints[0][2] = ints[0][1];
        ints[0] = ints[1];
        ints[0][2] = ints[0][1];
        ints[1] = a;
    }`

Comment: In ints[0]=ints[1]; you just change the reference of ints[0] and not the values of your "file" A is referring to. Meaning ints[0] is now the same link as ints[1]. The "file" A was referring to stays untouched. In Vlads diagram this means, you change the arrow, not the contents.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor changes ints[][] around:

```
int[] a = {0,1,2} //references ints[0]
ints[0][2] = ints[0][1] // ints[][] = {{0,1,1},{3,4,5},{6,7,8}}
// a = {0,1,1} since it references ints[0]
ints[0] = ints[1] // ints[][] = {{3,4,5},{3,4,5},{6,7,8}} 
//changes reference of ints[0], a[] still pointing to old reference
ints[1] = a // ints[][] = {{3,4,5},{0,1,1},{6,7,8}
//points ints[1] back to a's reference
//final ints: {{3,4,5},{0,1,1},{6,7,8}
```

i starts as -1.
++i increments before comparing, so the first while check is 0 < ints.length (which is currently 3).
i is now 0
total is 1

```
for j = 0; j < 3; j++
j = 0
    if (j%2 == 0) //true
        total += 3 //total = 4
j = 1
    if (j%2 == 0) //false
        total -= ints[0][1] //4, total = 0
j = 2
    if (j%2 == 0) //true
        total += ints[0][2] //5, total = 5
j = 3
    Print "5"
```

i is now 1
total is 1

```
for j = 0; j < 3; j++
j = 0
    if (j%2 == 0) //true
        total += ints[1][0] //0, total = 1
j = 1
    if (j%2 == 0) //false
        total -= ints[1][1] //1, total = 0
j = 2
    if (j%2 == 0) //true
        total += ints[1][2] //1, total = 1
j = 3
    Print "1"
```

i is now 2
total is 1

```
for j = 0; j < 3; j++
j = 0
    if (j%2 == 0) //true
        total += ints[2][0] //6, total = 7
j = 1
    if (j%2 == 0) //false
        total -= ints[2][1] //7, total = 0
j = 2
    if (j%2 == 0) //true
        total += ints[2][2] //8, total = 8
j = 3
    Print "8"
```

Final output:

5

1

8

(Println will print on separate lines, so for "518" you'd need to just System.out.print())

Answer (score 0):

after getting instance of pin this array look like:

{3,4,5}

{0,1,1}

{6,7,8}

when i = 0(traversing row 0) total = 1+3-4+5=5

when i = 1(traversing row 1) total = 1+0-1+1=1

when i = 2(traversing row 2) total = 1+6-7+8=8